# How to combine Maps with different value types in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, collections, types

I have the following code which is working:

```
case class Step() {
  def bindings(): Map[String, Any] = ???
}

class Builder {
  private val globalBindings = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Any]
  private val steps = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Step]

  private def context: Map[String, Any] =
    globalBindings.foldLeft(Map[String, Any]())((l, r) => l + r) ++ Map[String, Any]("steps" -> steps.foldLeft(Vector[Map[String, Any]]())((l, r) => l.+:(r.bindings)))
}
```

But I think it could be simplified so as to not need the first foldLeft in the 'context' method.

The desired result is to produce a map where the entry values are either a String, an object upon which toString will be invoked later, or a function which returns a String.

Is this the best I can do with Scala's type system or can I make the code clearer?

TIA

Comment: best to stay away from `Any` 99% of the time — you're not writing Java (anymore) :)

Comment: Why do the value type have to be different? Don't they all evaluate to `String` ? It can be a function that _evaluates_ to `String`. The function should be able to handle the logic of how to evaluate to a given String value.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `toMap` method on `mutable.HashMap` returns an `immutable.Map`.  You can also use `map` instead of the inner `foldLeft` together with `toVector` if you really need a vector, which might be unnecessary.  Finally, you can just use `+` to add the desired key-value pair of "steps" to the map.

So your whole method body could be:

```
globalBindings.toMap + ("steps" -> steps.map(_.bindings).toVector)
```

I'd also note that you should be apprehensive of using types like `Map[String, Any]` in Scala.  So much of the power of Scala comes from its type system and it can be used to great effect in many such situations, and so these types are often considered unidiomatic.  Of course, there are situations where this approach makes the most sense, and without more context it would be hard to determine if that were true here.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I knew that the Any was a smell just wasn't sure how to correct it. What about the val declarations, e.g. globalBindings, can they be written otherwise or do they have to have the Any type as they could be String, toStringable, or a ( => String) function?

Comment: You could make a wrapper trait that includes all of these types, and then use that as the value type of the map.

Comment: That sounds good but pushing the limits of my Scala-foo, could you give me any more pointers? Do you mean something like https://workday.github.io/scala/2015/02/05/scala-typesafe-wrappers/